# Leave small space between buttons when using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout, jtoolbar

I am trying to create a toolbar that will go at the top of all the pages in my java swing application.

I am creating a JPanel with a series of individual JPanels (containers) inside it. Each JPanel (container) has a north and south component or just a north component, set up using a GridLayout.

My problem is, I want a small gap between the north and south component, but I can't see how to do it and have not been able to find any help on the internet.

Below is a working example for the code for one of the containers:

```
public static void CustomersGui(){

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nested Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel container1 = new JPanel();
        container1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JButton buttonDiary = new JButton("Diary");
        buttonDiary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 25));
        JButton buttonCars = new JButton("Cars");
        buttonCars.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 25));
        container1.add(buttonDiary, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container1.add(buttonCars, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        frame.setContentPane(container1);

        frame.pack();


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Note that the `GridLayout` has a constructor that additionally allows you to specify a "hgap" and "vgap": The size of a gap between the components, horizontally and vertically. Alternatively, assigning an `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,2,3,4)` to the *inner* component is one possible way of adding empty spaces (but should only be used if there is no appropriate layout option to achieve the desired goal)

Comment: Please have a look at [providing whitespace, in a Swing GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/1057230). Hopefully this will help :-)

Comment: Moreover, you can use [Border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html), with any Swing component :-)

Answer (score 5):

> *I am trying to create a toolbar that will go at the top of all the pages in my java swing application.*

Why don't just use [JToolBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html)? See [How to use Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)

> *I am creating a JPanel with a series of individual JPanels (containers) inside it. Each JPanel (container) has a north and south
>   component or just a north component, set up using a GridBagLayout.*

Based on your code none of these statements is true: you are adding buttons (not panels) and you are using [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) not [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html):

```
JPanel container1 = new JPanel();
container1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1)); // GridLayout
JButton buttonDiary = new JButton("Diary"); // button here
buttonDiary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 25));
JButton buttonCars = new JButton("Cars"); // another button here
```

Besides you are using `BorderLayout` constraints that will be totally ignored by either `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`:

```
container1.add(buttonDiary, BorderLayout.NORTH);
container1.add(buttonCars, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

You should have a look to the whole [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson to learn about layout managers and how do all of them work.

#### In addition

As wisely pointed out by @nIcEcOw, since Java 1.4 `BorderLayout` the use of new constants is highly encouraged:

```
PAGE_START
PAGE_END
LINE_START
LINE_END
CENTER
```

From [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) tutorial (bold text mine):

> Before JDK release 1.4, the preferred names for the various areas were
>   different, ranging from points of the compass (for example,
>   `BorderLayout.NORTH` for the top area) to wordier versions of the
>   constants we use in our examples. ***The constants our examples use are
>   preferred because they are standard and enable programs to adjust to
>   languages that have different orientations.***

### Update

Well now that your question has been edited to say that you actually use `GridLayout` it's easy to answer by saying that you can specify horizontal and vertical gaps between components either by using class' constructor: or `setHgap()` and `setVgap()` methods:

```
JPanel container1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 8, 8));

// Or

GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
gridLayout.setRows(2);
gridLayout.setColumns(1);
gridLayout.setHgap(8);
gridLayout.setVgap(8);    
JPanel container1 = new JPanel(gridLayout);
```

Don't forget to remove `BorderLayout` constraints when you add buttons to `container1` panel, because those will be ignored:

```
container1.add(buttonDiary);
container1.add(buttonCars);
```

You might want to take a look to this topic as well: [Providing white space in a Swing GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874717/providing-white-space-in-a-swing-gui)

Comment: Please try to use `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` and `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` for `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH` respectively. Java is actively, encouraging programmers to write the new names instead of the previous one's since JDK 1.4 :-)

Comment: @dic19 if you read the question properly you will see it says this is a working example of the code for one of the containers. The code was edited to comply with MCVE principles

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @nIcEcOw Bad habits are hard to leave behind. I've just edited my answer to include your comment :D

Comment: Emmm... It's Minimal and Complete, but not Verifiable: it doesn't reproduce your problem. At least the problem stated in the question: *Leave small space between buttons when using GridBagLayout*. @jim

Comment: @dic19, you are right, I have now edited to say GridLayout. You were incorrect in your first criticism but correct in your second.

Comment: Please see my update. Hope you can solve your problem now :) @jim